# Add CSS Class in razor Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add css class in existing razor dropdownList. Here is my code

```
var webHelper = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWebHelper>();

var currencies = Model.AvailableCurrencies.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.Name,
        Value = webHelper.ModifyQueryString(Url.RouteUrl("ChangeCurrency", new { customercurrency = x.Id }), "returnurl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl), null),
        Selected = x.Id.Equals(Model.CurrentCurrencyId)                                  
    });

@Html.DropDownList("customerCurrency", currencies, new { onchange = "setLocation(this.value);" })
```

I have to make the dropdown list a bootstrap dropdownlist like this...

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="#">USD&nbsp;
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
    </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a>USD</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a>BDT</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a>EU</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
@Html.DropDownList("customerCurrency", currencies, new { onchange = "setLocation(this.value);", @class="dropdown-menu" })
```

Taking a short look at the [Bootstrap documentation for dropdowns](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation#dropdowns), it appears that you need to apply the class `dropdown`. However, the dropdown rendering of the default Html helper might not correspond to the dropdown rendering required by the Bootstrap dropdown, hence your class does not have the desired effect.

EDIT (following your MVC4 comment):

To mimic the functionality of the Bootstrap dropdown, you could try using this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="#">USD&nbsp;
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach(var currency in Model.AvailableCurrencies)
        {
             <li><a href="your new target">@currency.Name</a></li>
        }     
    </ul>
</li>
```

You could also try to use `Html.ActionLink` instead of the "static" `a` element.

Comment: The Class is added but the UI isn't changing as it should do.
Looks like it doesn't work.Sorry

Comment: @user3239764, be sure to add the correct class name. I'm not familiar with Bootstrap. You might need to add the `droptdown` class instead of `dropdown-menu`.

Comment: I have added the exact class. But whenever the class is added the dropdownlist is just gone. It should not be gone, but should add some styles on it.

Comment: @user3239764, I don't know what version of MVC you are using. If you are using MVC5, you should be able to render a Bootstrap dropdown by using [this](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation#dropdowns). If you are using an earlier version of MVC, then you are rendering the dropdowns using a different HTML layout. This layout (`select`) does not have the same structure as the Bootstrap one (`ul`, `li`, etc). In this case, you might have to mimic the Bootstrap layout in your view.

Comment: I am using MVC4 . Is there any way to create those dropdownlinks, navs or etc on MVC4 using bootstrap-3 ? How can i dynamically add those data on the lists as i wrote on that functions above in the question ? any help with the code please...

Comment: It requires license to fully configure. It give 30 days trial for free. Isn't Bootstrap an open source??

Comment: @user3239764, Bootstrap3 requires a license. See [here](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Home/Installation).

Comment: @user3239764, you're welcome. Btw, (pure) Bootstrap is free but the MVC extension methods require that you buy a license. You can still use the Bootstrap layout without having to pay.